# How to replace from current point to the next searched character in Emacs?

Tags: vim, emacs

I am trying out emacs and I wanted to know how I can do the following in the below text

```
ksdjf lsfjdslfj sjkfdlkfjsl sdflkjsfkldjf" sklfjklfjds f slfjdklsfjslfjdskfsdklfdjfkljskl sfklsdjfldsfj
```

From the second word lsfjdslfj I want to move till the " character and replace the entire region.

In Vim I'd do `vf"c blah` to get

```
ksdjf  blah sklfjklfjds f slfjdklsfjslfjdskfsdklfdjfkljskl sfklsdjfldsfj
```

Is there anything similar in Emacs? I am trying to understand the whole Emacs philosophy in movements and editing.

Comment: In Emacs you have [zap to char](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/ZapToChar), which will delete up to (and including) a given character. Normally bound to `M-z`.

Comment: @Juancho really cool. This is what I was looking for.

Comment: you can try using evil plugin, which simulate vim

Comment: @SolaWing I am looking at the Emacs way of doing things to evaluate which is better, so far it looks like vim takes lesser keystrokes.

Comment: Emacs's max power is it's extensibility. you can do everything in emacs. even simulate vim perfectly. But in the way of operating text, I think vim is more effective.

Comment: @Juancho: Please provide your comment as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Emacs, you have [zap to char](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/ZapToChar), which will delete up to (and including) a given character. It is normally bound to `M-z`.

To delete up to (and including) a string, one option is:

```
C-s      # incremental search
string   # whatever you are searching
C-x C-x  # go back to start point and mark region
C-w      # cut region
```